What is the limit on github releases
Is there any limit on the number of all your releases, or their total storage?
The documentation states that Each file included in a release must be under 2 GiB. There is no limit on the total size of a release, nor bandwidth usage. What I would like to know is:

Can I have as many releases as I want without any total storage limits as long as each file in each release is under 2G?
How is the answer different for private repositories, and specially company owned private repositories?

